# Suppose $\int^x_0 tf(t) \, dt = x\sin(x) + \cos(x) - 1$ for $x > 0$, find $f(\pi)$

Tags: calculus

Suppose $\int^x_0 tf(t) \, dt = x\sin(x) + \cos(x) - 1$ for $x > 0$, find $f(π)$. $f$ is continuous.

My solution is as follows:

$$\left(\int^x_0 tf(t)\,dt\right)' = (x\sin x + \cos x - 1)'$$

$xf(x) = \sin x + x\cos x + \cos x$ (By Fundamental theorem of Calculus 2)

$$f(x) = \frac{\sin x + x\cos x + \cos x}{x}$$

And finding $f(\pi)$ is trivial from there.

Did I make a mistake with my solution? I did not make use of the 1 in the problem and I believe I missed something of importance.

Comment: Is that formula true for all $x$ or for a particular $x$?

Comment: looks like i misread the question, it's true for $x > 0$, though I don't see how it changes anything

Comment: To apply the fundamental theorem of calculus, you need to know that the formula is true for all $x$ in a neighbourhood of the point where you're evaluating the derivative. i.e to say that $x_0 f(x_0) = \sin x_0 + x_0 \cos x_0 + \cos x_0$, you need to know that there is a neighbourhood of $x_0$ such that for all $x$ in that neighbourhood, $\int_0^x t f(t)\, dt = x \sin x + \cos x$. But if this is really the case, then it is not possible for this function to be identically equal to $1$ (even in that open neighbourhood), so I suspect there is something weird with this question.

Comment: Based on context, I assume the "$=1$" is meant to be a $-1$.

Comment: it is a -1, apologies

Comment: Ah yes, in that case, your approach is correct, but recheck your derivative calculation on the RHS

Comment: thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not take the derivative of the cos(x) term at the end, which would become -sin(x) and cancel the one at the beginning. From this it would follow that f(x) = cos(x) and thus $f(\pi) = cos(\pi) = -1$